# How to interpret factor analysis output here

Tags: factor-analysis, item-response-theory

I am using [girth](https://pypi.org/project/girth/) package which uses polychoric correlation and then applies factor analysis. I am using the example  code given on above webpage under the subheading "Polychoric Correlation Estimation":

```
import girth.synthetic as gsyn
import girth.factoranalysis as gfa
import girth.common as gcm

discrimination = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, (20, 2))
thetas = np.random.randn(2, 1000)
difficulty = np.linspace(-1.5, 1, 20)

syn_data = gsyn.create_synthetic_irt_dichotomous(difficulty, discrimination, thetas)

polychoric_corr = gcm.polychoric_correlation(syn_data, start_val=0, stop_val=1)

results_fa = gfa.maximum_likelihood_factor_analysis(polychoric_corr, 2)
```

The data (20 columns and 1000 rows) is as follows:

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1     0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
2     0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
3     0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
4     0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
..   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
995   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
996   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1
997   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
998   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1
999   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
```

The correlation matrix created is as follows:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6   ...        13        14        15        16        17        18        19
0   1.000000 -0.372014 -0.242639 -0.450080  0.130449  0.453910  0.016924  ... -0.340188 -0.507171  0.482642 -0.018359 -0.285936 -0.422905  0.226303
1  -0.372014  1.000000  0.149975  0.333496 -0.195981 -0.301749  0.010126  ...  0.248877  0.353242 -0.360966 -0.032249  0.300746  0.250678 -0.176474
2  -0.242639  0.149975  1.000000  0.020036 -0.187157 -0.149063 -0.502865  ... -0.129884  0.294766  0.026245 -0.240363  0.511740  0.374489 -0.117930
3  -0.450080  0.333496  0.020036  1.000000 -0.043634 -0.372508  0.201392  ...  0.328995  0.395505 -0.534622  0.075794  0.159446  0.353241 -0.218804
4   0.130449 -0.195981 -0.187157 -0.043634  1.000000  0.171968  0.192930  ...  0.123934 -0.156043 -0.011919  0.139299 -0.245182 -0.232658  0.080830
5   0.453910 -0.301749 -0.149063 -0.372508  0.171968  1.000000  0.022395  ... -0.276296 -0.418714  0.473535 -0.014285 -0.327602 -0.396633  0.226920
6   0.016924  0.010126 -0.502865  0.201392  0.192930  0.022395  1.000000  ...  0.344361 -0.125337 -0.234694  0.301752 -0.356692 -0.280085 -0.069264
7  -0.037914  0.011994  0.507751 -0.162141 -0.275842 -0.081360 -0.574436  ... -0.311638  0.158223  0.177512 -0.366945  0.529308  0.364736 -0.033857
8   0.562803 -0.378088 -0.071710 -0.498235  0.053983  0.418691 -0.184258  ... -0.443017 -0.400253  0.601103 -0.105491 -0.121025 -0.337324  0.243227
9  -0.529324  0.384604  0.154708  0.516636 -0.123017 -0.397763  0.155550  ...  0.321337  0.401681 -0.478831  0.009805  0.321941  0.389378 -0.307586
10  0.361794 -0.220212  0.048604 -0.334888  0.000692  0.273246 -0.304177  ... -0.394676 -0.211652  0.400769 -0.186524 -0.049662 -0.181061  0.131394
11 -0.518512  0.239324  0.148274  0.309680 -0.025221 -0.344541  0.025191  ...  0.282115  0.429718 -0.422606 -0.010329  0.232012  0.388386 -0.213912
12  0.024234  0.021528  0.358700 -0.120740 -0.177754 -0.043941 -0.356709  ... -0.237652  0.057160  0.188560 -0.237153  0.263305  0.191856  0.007850
13 -0.340188  0.248877 -0.129884  0.328995  0.123934 -0.276296  0.344361  ...  1.000000  0.210238 -0.519403  0.170950 -0.051980  0.103658 -0.209891
14 -0.507171  0.353242  0.294766  0.395505 -0.156043 -0.418714 -0.125337  ...  0.210238  1.000000 -0.429463 -0.028562  0.372955  0.461054 -0.194371
15  0.482642 -0.360966  0.026245 -0.534622 -0.011919  0.473535 -0.234694  ... -0.519403 -0.429463  1.000000 -0.071710 -0.240631 -0.385008  0.242634
16 -0.018359 -0.032249 -0.240363  0.075794  0.139299 -0.014285  0.301752  ...  0.170950 -0.028562 -0.071710  1.000000 -0.207235 -0.197238 -0.070399
17 -0.285936  0.300746  0.511740  0.159446 -0.245182 -0.327602 -0.356692  ... -0.051980  0.372955 -0.240631 -0.207235  1.000000  0.459764 -0.125293
18 -0.422905  0.250678  0.374489  0.353241 -0.232658 -0.396633 -0.280085  ...  0.103658  0.461054 -0.385008 -0.197238  0.459764  1.000000 -0.145590
19  0.226303 -0.176474 -0.117930 -0.218804  0.080830  0.226920 -0.069264  ... -0.209891 -0.194371  0.242634 -0.070399 -0.125293 -0.145590  1.000000
```

The results of factor analysis are as follows:

```
(array([[ 0.0419671 , -0.73520752],
       [-0.03984031,  0.50963606],
       [-0.64915359,  0.24317354],
       [ 0.1862389 ,  0.64211114],
       [ 0.31887008, -0.15306844],
       [ 0.07858975, -0.61287159],
       [ 0.73044949,  0.07450868],
       [-0.80897573,  0.02504498],
       [-0.21818786, -0.73632751],
       [ 0.04928449,  0.70744866],
       [-0.29856161, -0.49485133],
       [-0.02069669,  0.58686592],
       [-0.52482931, -0.04802906],
       [ 0.41904667,  0.48510999],
       [-0.20016447,  0.63688427],
       [-0.2389381 , -0.7398583 ],
       [ 0.41800295,  0.01914967],
       [-0.58684168,  0.42456658],
       [-0.40758167,  0.58997834],
       [-0.01106376, -0.33936853]]), 

  array([3.12844677, 5.14338998]), 

  array([0.45770867, 0.73868383, 0.51946626, 0.55300836, 0.87489192,
       0.61821207, 0.46089202, 0.34493097, 0.41021586, 0.49708743,
       0.66598313, 0.65516004, 0.72224741, 0.58906818, 0.55431261,
       0.39551828, 0.82490682, 0.47536005, 0.48580274, 0.88470659]))
```

There are 3 arrays in the output. What do these 3 arrays represent? How does one interpret this output? Thanks for your insight.

Edit: It is surprising that there is no answer posted for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `girth` package, though after some reading I believe I have the answer.

1. The first array corresponds to a 20 x 2 factor loading matrix $\Lambda$.
2. The second array corresponds to each of the two factors eigenvalue.
3. The third array corresponds to diag($\Psi$) which contains each items unexplained variance. This can be confirmed by subtracting each items commonality $h$ from 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will be useful if you can also briefly write how are these results to be interpreted?